Expected maximum number of consecutive heads in $n$ tosses
I am a relative novice in probability and statistics. I am faced with the problem:

What is the expected maximum number of consecutive heads in $n$ tosses?

That is, if I measure $0000010011101$ with $1=$ heads, then the maximum is 3; I am looking for the expected maximum in $n$ tosses.
I don't have the background to derive this by myself, and while many other questions seem related, they aren't quite what I'm looking for (e.g. expected number of tosses to achieve $k$ consecutive heads).
This problem arose from a (probabilistic) quantum computing algorithm I am designing.
